# Detect Connectivity change using JobScheduler

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-jobscheduler

As `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` intent filter is deprecated in Android N, how to detect Connectivity change by using JobScheduler?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: can anyone provide sample code that, how to implement it for adnroid N.Using  broadcast receiver statically not working in android N

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48666854/5315559