# Best way to start a task when connectivity is available again? (API 24 or higher)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-syncadapter

As mentioned in [Android 7.0 changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes), apps targeting Android API 24 or higher do not receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they declare their broadcast receiver in the manifest.

I implement a sync adapter to check and synchronized pending data with the server, but I am only able to set a periodic time to schedule the task.

How messaging apps, like whatsapp,  can upload pending data as soon as connection is available again?

Are they using a JobService scheduled with `RequiredNetworkType`set as `JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY`?

Comment: Look at it [Detect connectivity change in Android 7 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527171/detect-connectivity-change-in-android-7-and-above-when-app-is-killed-in-backgrou)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I think the best solution is the one provided by the Android documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization#connectivity-action

Answer (score 0):

After many research I found a solution provided by Android documentation.
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization#connectivity-action