# android on connect to network listener background

Tags: android

What is the best way to do this after version (7.0)
I was doing this using "BroadcastReceiver" but after version (7.0) Problems began to appear 
I try to use "GcmTaskService" and "JobScheduler"
But I did not find the way right.
can any one help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect CONNECTIVITY CHANGE in Android 7 and above when app is killed/in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527171/detect-connectivity-change-in-android-7-and-above-when-app-is-killed-in-backgrou)

Answer (score 2):

RxAndroid (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) offers really helpful tools for reacting to asynchronous processes.

Specifically pertaining to network connectivity you can begin the connection using the built in android NetworkManager and WifiConfiguration and observe connectivity using the RxAndroid ReactiveNetwork static methods.

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.ssid = "\"SecureNetwork\"" //Note that quote characters are required in the SSID
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

WifiManager wifiManger = (WifiManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifiManager == null) {
    //error handling - make sure you have permissions etc
}

int connectionId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
if (connectionId == -1) {
    //Network is already configured - find configuration using wifiManger.getConfiguredNetworks();
}

wifiManager.enableNetwork(connectionId, true); //Attempt to connect to network

//Now use RxAndroid ReactiveNetwork to observe connectivity

ReactiveNetwork.observeNetworkConnectivity(context)
    .filter(ConnectivityPredicate.hasState(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))
    .filter(ConnectivityPredicate.hasType(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI))
    .flatMap(connectivity -> {
        int currentNetId = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
        if (currentNetId == connectionNetId) {
             return Observable.just(true);
        } else {
             return Observable.error("Not connected to new network")
        }
    .doOnNext(mBoolean -> //Do whatever you want to now that you are connect)
    .doOnError(mError ->> //Handle error)
    .suscribe();
```