# Detect Connectivity Change When App is Killed/In Background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, jobservice

I'd like to detect when there is a network change (connection\disconnection) when my app is **not in the foreground**, so I can sync the user's data.

I have tried to use a `broadcast receiver` (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44881551/7483311) answer) but the broadcasts are no longer received when the app is closed (after `Android N`). It only works when the app is in the foreground.

In order to detect connectivity change in the background, I have tried to use the `Job Scheduler` (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48666854/7483311) answer) with the `.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)` parameter, but my problem is that the job is done repetitively (every 15 minutes), even when the user is **still connected** to the internet.

My goal is to make the job **once** when the internet connection is regained, and then stop the job until the user disconnects and connects again. The job should be done **once** for every connection to the internet, and then wait until a reconnection (without repeating it).

Is it possible to achieve this with the `Job Scheduler` (or in any other way)?

Comment: work manager is a good option for this. as it will decide to run broadcast of network or  it use job scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to achieve this with the Job Scheduler?
Answer - I don't know BUT
You can use **WorkManager**. That is part of Android Jetpack.

There are 2 options.

1) OneTimeWorkRequest (that what you need).
2) PeriodicWorkRequest (executes periodically, min time is 15 minutes, same as jobScheduler).

WorkManager executes only 10 seconds, as jobscheduler.

Why is WorkManager good. Image in below will give answer.
[image]

[image]

Documentation - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: Thanks. Can you please add a code example? I'm not familiar with this tool at all.

Comment: 1) https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hgI250AJXKsQH_4X3gRRaMg  -  Video tutorials, I think one of the best ))

Comment: 2) Google codelabs tutorial - https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#0  I think this will help you to understand this. If my answer helped, please give vote and accept it :) Good luck ))