# How to implement Internet Connection listener for each Activity using JobScheduler and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-jobscheduler, android-connectivitymanager

I want to check if user has available connection to the internet and show `Snackbar` for him or other custom action.

**App's minSdk is 23 (Android 6.0).**

Since **Android 7.0** there were some changes to `BroadcastReceiver` and receiving connection status. Now i have to use `JobScheduler` and `Service` to check connection status.

I've found tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48666854/9046350)

But he is initializing `JobScheduler` inside `NetworkConnectionActivity`. I did this at the start of `Application` class where other services are initialized (like `FirebaseMessagingService`).

What I want to achieve is to implement `ConnectivityReceiverListener` to multiple Activities in my App and override `onNetworkConnectionChanged` to get info when connection is changed. I will make custom reaction to this status depends on current `Activity`

Problem with this solution:  As I implement that listener in my `MainActivity` it is not fired. But toast inside `onNetworkConnectionChanged` in `NetworkSchedulerService` was fired

Example Code:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener{


        var mConnectionSnackbar: Snackbar? = null
        override fun onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected: Boolean) {
            App.log("ConnectionChanged: $isConnected")
            app.isConnected = isConnected
            maybeShowConnectionSnackbar(isConnected)
        }

        fun maybeShowConnectionSnackbar(isConnected: Boolean){
            if (isConnected){
                mConnectionSnackbar?.dismiss()
            } else {
                if (mConnectionSnackbar == null){
                    mConnectionSnackbar = Snackbar.make(content, "Connection Lost", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                }
            }
        }
     **** onCreate and variable init ***
    }
```

Function in `Application` class:

```
private fun createConnectivityJobScheduler(){
        val myJob = JobInfo.Builder(0, ComponentName(this, NetworkSchedulerService::class.java))
                .setMinimumLatency(1000)
                .setOverrideDeadline(2000)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .build()

        val jobScheduler = getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
        jobScheduler.schedule(myJob)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
val serviceComponent = ComponentName(context, CallJob()::class.java)
val builder = JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent)
builder.setMinimumLatency((30000).toLong())
builder.setOverrideDeadline((300000).toLong())
val jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler::class.java)

try {
    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build())
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

before that you need to check weather the scheduler was currently running or not..

Comment: Tried this and it doesnt even fire from NetworkSchedulerService